# How should I fix backward angular velocity upon moving a constraint in MatterJS?

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I'm creating a constraint between a body and a point:

```
var tempConstraint = Constraint.create({pointA: {x: 50, y: 50}, bodyB: body, pointB: {x: x, y: y}, stiffness: 0.1, length: 0, damping: 0.5, });
```

The point is also being moved around:

```
tempConstraint.pointA = {x: newX, y: newY};
```

The issue is that if `pointA` is moved slowly from left to right, for example, the body its dragging moves the opposite direction to what it should be. For example, if you dangle a pencil by the very tip and start moving the tip to the right, the bottom of the pencil should start to hang slightly to the left of the top as it moves. However, if I were to do that exact thing with the above code, the bottom of the pencil flies over to the right, exactly as it should if the top were being pulled left. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here but my only thought is that changing `pointA` is a bad idea, but I can't really come up with a better way to move the constraint point. Would creating a collision disabled, static body and attaching it to that, and then moving the body be a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me, although I'm using a spring constraint. I've also removed the length property in the constraint so the length is auto generated:

```
var vw = window.innerWidth/100;
var vh = window.innerHeight/100;
var body = Bodies.rectangle(vw*50, vh*50, vw*3, vw*15, {
    frictionAir: 0.02,
    friction: 1,
    render: {
        fillStyle: "#FCED08"
    }
});
var tempConstraint = Constraint.create({pointA: {x: vw*50, y: vh*50}, bodyB: body, pointB: {x:0,y:vw*7.5}, stiffness: 0.8, damping: 0.5, render: {type: "spring"}});
World.add(world, [body, tempConstraint]);
```

The full code is [here](https://codepen.io/Tians/pen/BELaoe)